# Move data to adjacent columns based on date (month) value

Tags: vba, excel

Moving expense data from columns K:M to respective columns N:Y (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.) based on date (month) in column AA, but any future dates in column AA are populating the data in the future (forward) and not historically as desired?

```
Sub MoveData() 
Dim vals As Range, val As Range, colOffset As Integer 
Set vals = Range("K2:K" & Range("K2").End(xlDown).Row) 

For Each val In vals 

 If val > 0 Then 
  colOffset = VBA.month(val.offset(0, 16)) 
  val.offset(0, colOffset) = val 
  val.offset(0, colOffset + 1) = val.offset(0, 1) 
  val.offset(0, colOffset + 2) = val.offset(0, 2) 
 End if 

 Next val 
End Sub
```

!Example[image]

Comment: Please show an example of your data.

Comment: I'll have a look once I also see an example of the data.

Comment: you have to move data from 3 columns ("K", "L", "M") in a range of 12 (from "N" to "Y") columns based on the month in column "AA". and you have data in column "Z".  1)  is the month to localize the first cell to move data into? 2) if yes, how to handle the case when the month is > 10 and so your moving data would overlap columns "Z" and "AA" data? 3) is data in column "Z"  significant for moving activity?

Comment: The month to localize the data is the final month in the 3 month string of expense data. Said another way, June date in column AA would populate in columns Q(April), R(May) and S(June) from column K(April), L(May) & M(June).

Comment: So the image you loaded up is an example of a "correct" moving, isn't it?

Comment: It's the incorrect image as the actual values being moved to June should be moving to April as June hasn't happened yet

Comment: Column "M" would be April data if column AA is a June date.  In May, April date would move to column L and column M would be the May data.  In June, column K would be April data and May would be in column L and June would appear in column M.  The data is fed from a mainframe and is formatted K:M which is oldest to newest and it would shift left on each successive month.  In other words, the data moved from columns K:M should never be moved in to a future month on columns N:Y as it wouldn't have happened yet.

Comment: Somehow the code needs to take into account that the data from K:M would never be moved into the future (beyond the current month) regardless of the date in column AA if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited after OP's further specs

not sure I grasped the logic you need, but try this

Option Explicit

```
Sub MoveData()
Dim colOffset As Integer, dataCols As Long
Dim datesRng As Range, dateRng As Range, valsRng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("expenses") '<== change it to your actual sheet name
    Set datesRng = .Range("AA2:AA" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'process rows as long as there's a "Transition Date"

    For Each dateRng In datesRng
        With .Range("K" & dateRng.Row)
            dataCols = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Resize(, 3))
            Set valsRng = .Offset(, 3 - dataCols).Resize(, dataCols)
        End With

        colOffset = WorksheetFunction.Min(Month(dateRng), Month(Date)) - dataCols 'limit month offset to current one and set it back to the numbers of values
        If colOffset >= 0 Then
            .Range("N" & dateRng.Row).Offset(, colOffset).Resize(, dataCols).Value = valsRng.Value
            .Range("N" & dateRng.Row).Offset(, colOffset).Value = .Range("N" & dateRng.Row).Offset(, colOffset) - .Range("J" & dateRng.Row).Value
        Else
            'some K-L columns data would be overwritten!!
        End If

    Next dateRng
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great!  One more ask please....Can the oldest of the 3 values moved in columns N:Y be reduced in the move macro by a numeric value that I have in column J?  In other words, can the first available value reflected in columns N:Y be somehow netted by the value in column J.

Comment: It removes the values located in column J, but not within the earliest month that the move data appears (I.e.:  The very first (Leftmost) column in range N:Y that is greater than zero)

Comment: Also, is there a way to not overwrite columns K-M if the date in column AA  spans a previous or subsequent year (2015 or 2017 for instance? and still populate columns N & O  or X & Y as applicable?

Comment: As for the value to be reduced: I edited the answer without the possibility of testing it and I'm still in the same position, but since the added line uses the same reference used in the preceeding statement that writes the moved values but without the resizeing to their full number then it should reference the first one and I couldn't say why is not reducing correctly. But you can step through the code and check what's happening and make needed revisions. If my answer fulfilled your original question please mark it as accepted. If you find my answer useful then you may up-vote it. Thank you.

Comment: Unable to determine why it's not netting out the first available left-most value in columns N:Y.   Perhaps someone can help further?

Comment: Just to confirm, it is reducing the original value, just not in the appropriate reference month (left to right) for some reason that I cannot figure out...